# My C++ linker isn't able to link properly without including .cpp files in my program

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, linker

My professor has pointed out that this isn't normal, but I have been struggling to fix the error.

I am using VSCode as my IDE, and have installed the C/C++ extensions. I haven't been able to find anyone else describing this error, and my professor has been unable to help me find the cause, and has told me to ask a coding community to look for help.

I fear that something may be corrupted with my linker, as that was a concern my professor had.

I am able to run my driver with all of these include statements:

```
#include "unsorted.h"
#include "DateType.h"
#include "PersonType.h"
#include "StudentType.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "DateType.cpp"
#include "PersonType.cpp"
#include "StudentType.cpp"
#include "unsorted.cpp"
using namespace std;
```

but if I comment out the `.cpp` files, the driver will fail to compile. My professor says I should only be including the `.h` files and not the `.cpp` files, but that causes errors.

I tried to comment out the `.cpp` files, but the code won't compile like that, even though it should only require the header file.

Why is this happening?

I changed my tasks.json file to include this

```
"type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\*.cpp",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
```

it didn't solve my issue. I am running windows 10, and can't fix this compiler bug. I can't find the source of the problem, and the related link didn't help.

Comment: Are you compiling the other cpp files

Comment: Don't ever `#include` .cpp files. Your build tools should  compile each .cpp file separately and link the resulting object files together.

Comment: @PeteBecker [Unity builds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_build) are a perfectly reasonable thing. They [are used](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/support-for-unity-jumbo-files-in-visual-studio-2017-15-8-experimental/) with Visual Studio by many.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz -- and `#include <bits/stdc.h>` is used by many, as well as `using namespace std;`. That doesn't make them a perfectly reasonable thing. Learning bad habits just leads to problems later in life.

Comment: @PeteBecker It's an [officially supported Visual Studio](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/9/2019/02/Unity-Build-Post.png) feature.

Comment: "*[my professor] has told me to ask a coding community to look for help*" - wow, that's a first! "*my professor has been unable to help me find the cause ... [he] says I should only be including the `.h` files and not the `.cpp` files*" - then he obviously knows the cause, but is unwilling to share the solution, or really doesn't know it himself. Either way, you should find a more competent professor. He is right about one thing, though - don't `#include` `.cpp` files. Your project should *compile* each `.cpp` file separately and then *link* the object files together, like Pete said.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz -- well, there you go: Microsoft is always right! <g>

Comment: My professor seems to know nothing about the VSCode IDE. I've been trying to get a solution from him for weeks but can't. I am unable to find the error in my tools? I replaced the code that needed to be replaced in tasks.json, but it still isn't compiling without the .cpp files.

Comment: @MrHupwop It should compile just fine. But you need to somehow link all the compiled code together. Are you compiling all the .cpp files?

Comment: Make sure that you are not using code-runner and that the task is being run. Look at the terminal for the exact build command that is run.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I can get it to compile but it requires me to write an include statement for every linked .cpp and .h file, which everyone is telling me not to do because it's improper. My professor is telling me to switch to Eclipse but I'm struggling  to run code there too.

Comment: @drescherjm I think this is my exact build command: cd "c:\Users\john3\C++ Workspace\PlusCode6\Chapter1\Fraction\" && g++ fracDr.cpp -o fracDr && "c:\Users\john3\C++ Workspace\PlusCode6\Chapter1\Fraction\"fracDr
Am I using code runner?

Comment: It does not appear to be using your tasks.json at all. That would happen if code-runner was active and possibly if you selected a build different task than the one you are showing us.

Comment: You may want to try the official VSCode tutorial which explains the 3 json files and shows you how to build a simple example.

Comment: @MrHupwop Your command is missing a `-c` to tell `g++` not to try to link the individual C++ file.